# How to refresh tab panel in ExtJS4?

Tags: extjs4

I have such a tab panel:

```
{
        xtype : "tabpanel",//
        region : "center",
        title : "name",
        id:"mytabpanel", 
        items : [ {
            title : "tab1"
        },{
            autoLoad: {url: 'test.jsp', scope: this},
            title: 'tab2',
            closable:false,
            autoScroll:true
            } ]
    }
```

Don't know how to refresh tab2 based on some parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AutoLoad` is deprecated since 4.1.1. Use [loader config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-loader) instead.

to (re)load your component. See [ComponentLoader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader) example